# Card swap permutations

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, permutation, playing-cards

So I have a full deck of cards in random order. My goal is to find 4 cards such that when their positions are swapped will yield a deck with the minimum total variance. So I need to perform two card swaps.

The total variance for a deck is defined as the sum of distances between successive cards within the deck.

Distance is defined as the difference between ranks, so the distance between ace of spades and 9 of clubs is 9-1 = 8.

So the total variance entails summing the distance between 1st and 2nd, and 2nd and 3rd and 3rd and 4th and so on.

A card swap is merely changing the position of a card in the array/list.

This is actually the 2nd part of the assignment.
The first part asked for the minimum total variance for one swap which I figured out. Essentially I used two for-loops to iteratively change positions of cards while comparing the total variance of the deck with the changed positions. My feeling is that the brute force approach in the first swap solution might not feasible for two swaps.

This is a snippet of the code for one swap solution:

```
for i, first_card in enumerate(data):
    new_deck = data
    TV= 600
    for j, second_card in enumerate(data):
        old_card = new_deck[i]
        new_deck[i] = second_card
        new_deck[j]= old_card
        new_TV = distance_cal(new_deck)
        if new_TV <TV:
            TV = new_TV
            TV_arr[i] = new_TV
            first_card = new_deck[i]
            second_card = new_deck[j]
            dict_list[i]= {"first_card":first_card,"second_card":second_card}
        new_deck = data
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @AlexReynolds The goal of the exercise is to find the best 4 cards to swap within a randomly ordered deck, so as to yield the minimum sum of absolute differences of that deck, where the absolute difference is defined as the difference between consecutive cards.

Comment: Hint #1: Most of the terms you must be summing in `distance_cal()` will be the same as in the original, untouched deck. I expect that running this function takes O(n) time. See if you can come up with a function that computes in just O(1) time the *change in* variance after swapping a pair of cards.

Comment: Brute force should still work for 2 swaps. It's slow for 3 swaps, and unworkable for 4 swaps. There are 270725 ways to choose 4 cards from a deck of 52. Then there are 3 ways to split the cards into 2 pairs. So you need to calculate the variance a total of 812175 times. If you are allowed to use the `itertools` package, you can generate the indexes with `for cards in combinations(range(52), 4)`. Inside the loop `cards` will be a tuple containing the indexes of four cards. Without itertools, you'll need to write four nested loops to select the indexes.

Comment: Hint #2: If a much faster algorithm is possible, it will require investigating properties of the input and the swaps you can make. Here's one that might be useful: Notice that if the first and third cards are, say, 3 and 10, and the second card is between 3 and 10 inclusive, the variance contributed by these 3 cards is exactly 10-3=7, regardless of what the second card is.

Comment: For `n` cards, with values `1, 2, ..., n-1, n`, the maximum variance is `n * n // 2 - 1`.

Comment: For `n` cards, the maximum change in variance with 2 swaps is `n - 1 + n - 2`.